# How to use traverse just a section of a RDD per day?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

This question is about the design of code. How to iterate parts of RDD today and another parts of it the next day.

I have built a RDD or a spark dataframe of 20,000,000 lines already. I want to invoke an API from lbs.amap.com but it can only be visited with 300,000 times per day.

```py
def gd_address(line):
    # GET rest api, return a list of values
    ...
# use these values to add columns to my RDD
df.rdd.map(lambda line: (line[0], line[1], gd_address(line)[0], gd_address(line)[1], gd_address(line)[2]), True)
```

How can I write a program when it just traverse 300,000 lines then stops, and then traverse the next 300,000 lines the next day and stops, util it has finished traversing the whole RDD? Any Idea will be appreciated.

Comment: Is there an ordering of the 20 mio lines? Do you have a preference of the order whereby the lines are processed? If not you could just add a new column `dfWithIndex = df.withColumn("index", monotonically_increasing_id())` and process the dataframe in chucks of 300.000 a day.

Comment: @Glennie Helles Sindholt As my spark must be executed automatically by some dispatch tools like airflow, how can I assure the chunks of data is different from yesterday?

Comment: If the order is irrelevant and you are fine with just attaching an index to you dataframe, then do that and persist it. Then write a simple piece of code that calculates the indices, such that on day 0 it reads and process index 0 to 299.999 of the dataframe, on day 1 it reads index 300.000-599.999 of the dataframe, and so forth...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already discussed with @Glennie the key point here is to use an unique incremental row id. That implies that new data will have an increasing incremental id and that id should remain the same for old data. In other words we need to make sure that one specific record will have the same corresponding id on each job execution. In order to create such unique id you can use `zipWithIndex` which is provided though the RDD API. On the contrary to monotonically_increasing_id the zipWithIndex function ensures sequential values of the row id. This will play significant role for the performance of your program since as we will see below it can reduce efficiently the number of rows that you need to process. Here is an implementation of the zipWithIndex approach:

```py
df.rdd.zipWithIndex() \
           .map(lambda (line, row_id): (row_id, line[0], line[1], gd_address(line)[0], gd_address(line)[1], gd_address(line)[2])) \
           .toDF(["row_id", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"])
```

The second prerequisite along with the existence of the unique row id is to sort your data based on the row id that we just created. Then for the first day the desired range will be 0 - 299.000 for the second day 300.000 - 599.999 for the third 600.000 - 899.999 and so on. After retrieving and processing each chunk you will need to store the last processed row id. You can choose to save the last id either on file system or in HDFS. One way to write to HDFS is via
`df.select("max(row_id)").write.text("hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/last_row_id.txt")` and reading with `spark.read.text("hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/last_row_id.txt")`.

Here is the complete code:

```py
def callAmapAPI(data):
   for row in data:
     # make HTTP call here

# assign row id to df 
df = df.rdd.zipWithIndex() \
           .map(lambda (line, row_id): (row_id, line[0], line[1], gd_address(line)[0], gd_address(line)[1], gd_address(line)[2])) \
           .toDF(["row_id", "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5"]) 

# retrieve saved row id
lower_bound_rowid = spark.read.text("hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/last_row_id.txt").first()[0]

chunk_size = 300000
upper_bound_rowid = lower_bound_id + chunk_size
partition_num = 8

# we restrict the number of rows to 300000 based on upper and lower bound
filtered_df = df.where(df["row_id"] > lower_bound_rowid &  df["row_id"] <= upper_bound_rowid) \
# optional allows more control to simultaneous calls to amap API i.e 8 concurrent HTTP calls
.repartition(partition_num, "row_id") \
.orderBy("row_id")

# call API for each partition
filtered_df.foreachPartition(callAmapAPI)

# save max row id for next day
filtered_df.select("max(row_id)") \
.write.mode('overwrite') \
.text("hdfs://cluster/user/hdfs/last_row_id.txt")
```

**Second approach using monotonically_increasing_id (not suggested)**

As for the approach using `monotonically_increasing_id` I believe that could work only if your dataset remains the same (there are no new rows) otherwise there is no way to guarantee that the generated_id will remain the same for each row hence you will not be able to track the last processed record (Spark may produce different id for the same record). Although if that is the case and the df doesn't change then you can call `monotonically_increasing_id()` only once and save the df with the new id added. In this case you will need the next two changes. First change the `df` definition to:

```py
df = df.withColumn("row_id", monotonically_increasing_id())
df.write.csv(...) # or some other storage
```

The above snippet should be executed only once on the contrary with the previous approach which calculates and assigns the row id on each job execution.

Then change the `filtered_df` definition to:

```py
df = spark.read.csv(...) # retrieve the dataset with monotonically_increasing_id

filtered_df = df.where(df["row_id"] > lower_bound_rowid) \
.orderBy("row_id") \
.limit(chunk_size) \
.repartition(partition_num, "row_id")
```

Two things to notice here. First we don't know the upper_bound_rowid (monotonically_increasing_id will produces arbitrary ids for each partition) and therefore upper_bound_rowid is not used in the where clause. Second the `orderBy` should occur before `limit` otherwise we can't ensure the topN rows. This approach also may have slower performance since `orderBy` is executed on a larger dataset.

Comment: Hello @Sky did you try this implementation?